# How to get generic function parameter type, when it depends on other parameter type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Sometimes we have a `library function` that we **can't change**, that the `second parameter type` depends of the `first parameter type`.

I'm need to export the `second parameter` as variable.

[Link for the minimal, reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=59&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSwEYCcCGKCeAxArmYKBcAFQAs0oB1AUwGE0wo6KwBzGmAXhgB4AoGDBIwaADyg0wAEwgxoKBOwA0gmAFEJ6AIyiJU2TABEAQSMwAPsYBCR1UM1R0AJj2SZcgAoYiaOLwBvGDA0AFsaAC55JyU2ZRg0DiiwXFCkGhQYAF8APn4AenyYUNw4IgAHOE5xJzQIfhyACjU0KJJ7GCQooLg0dLg2+KhMcsiNLTRteNGUCHAoxxds-gBKbhyYALUUGihcFDBjI34s-gKixFQMHHxCYjBySloGJhZGDkajADMEWahvdDhSQoOwwFbnGBUMhSGAIGDlHYQOQQcpoYA0IbQ+Q0UAyeEYMK7DIwChyKBYr4gOBwEAAd1iMGGowiEK2hSE8D6NAGxh+fwBhOBRgA3BChEyxqZzFYjLZhfCMnMwFEAb5-EEQuEogpYvLEmMUmkMvLcqL2ad2QBCGAASRgtMYsHJCDJIxoZytwjILthchAAGt4khcLBpOBYBQAG6cCXyXBsDjQe71XHQGA-anEng9Lk876-aACoEZUESqJS6aK+abLLZBJyVNQfiXdBYPAEIikCjUeiOt7sGifPmFgnFkHxDNVFDgiHW8g+sNMe0gFCBzo4tC4CCcOr+9MrhLU4w1dDmVGAomzfixkhu7gwIuXiC8CUgL7wZCtm4d+6PHsvZhWA4Xh835UdLyMHIcgAbW0ABdfhG3TBBMxQZw2jvbNOX6cth3+cChSGN1yzMStZmrAJa1OFtrnbO4uyeXtXiAwdQJHC9COQ1DnBWIA)

```
const libraryFunctionThatWeCantChange = <
  T extends string,
  Extra1 extends "A" | "B",
  Extra2 extends Partial<{ name: string, age: number }>
// multiple extras
>(
  a: T,
  b: { label: T, type: Extra1, person: Extra2 }
) => {
  return ""
}

// libraryFunctionThatWeCantChange("firstParameter", )
// When i press space, the second parameter has the following type:
// {
//   label: "firstParameter";
//   type: "A" | "B"; person: Partial<{ name: string; age: number; }>;
// }
// ! I want this type

// ! This is ok, but dont have type suggestions
const filler = { label: "firstParameter", type: "A", person: {} } as const
libraryFunctionThatWeCantChange("firstParameter", filler)

// ! This dont work, because ask for all "extra" parameters
type Type = Parameters<typeof libraryFunctionThatWeCantChange<"firstParameter">>[1]
const filler2: Type = { label: "firstParameter", type: "A", person: {} }
libraryFunctionThatWeCantChange("firstParameter", filler2)
```

[Link for the real world problem, with images](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73179344/3)

Comment: I'm not positive that I interpreted your question correctly. Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxDAxm) what you want? If so, I can post an answer based on that. If not, can you clarify further?

Comment: I am also unsure of your goal. Why not put it the other way round? [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgIwgGwCrggHlVCAPYCAOwBMBnKM4AJwEsiBzKAHyiIFcBbJagPigC8UAN5RkiFAC4oqANxRaJaQCIAgspZRlAIQ0BfWQChDAYwD2RKlE4gAYuyInBUTAAVcBYuUo16TVhzcEHwAFHDSrgA0UAjS8EhoGG68AJSC-MKGUFDUEMDs1ERQcEYGhkA)

Comment: Hi guys. I've improved the question with example of what i need, more specifically

Comment: @jsejcks Its no this code, because the generics of my use has a lot of arguments, and i need to pass all

Comment: @MarcelWaldvogel Its because i cant change the function definition

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/438273) Instead post the code itself as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edited the whole question, trying to be more objective

Comment: 1. For `Parameters<…>` to work, you would need to pass enough information that all the generics can be inferred by the compiler, similar to what you would need to define a variable where you could assign the function to.
2. Assume the library function API will not change too frequently. Then you can still define a `LabelType<T>` which has a signature matching parameter 2, at least for the parameters you will use it for (TypeScript does Duck Typing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand very well, can you show me in practice how your suggestions would solve the example problem? @MarcelWaldvogel

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the type safety you're looking for would be to wrap the library function and derive the parameter you're looking for.

```
type SecondParam = {
  label: string,
  type: "A" | "B"
  person: Partial<{ name: string, age: number }>
};

export const myWrapper = (secondParam: SecondParam, ...rest) => {
  libraryFunctionThatWeCantChange(secondParam.label, secondParam, ...rest);
}
```

It seems like the library you're consuming either has extremely complex typings? I'm not totally sure, but generally you shouldn't need to pass duplicated data to functions. You're already passing that info in the second argument, so the library should just unpack it under the hood. In any case, it sounds like you might want to declare some of your own typings over top of it.

Answer extended from [@marcel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445204/marcel-waldvogel) comment.

Comment: Adding some (possibly several) specialized wrappers which suit your usage (and typing) seems to be the best choice for this kind of problem.

Comment: Yes, the library that i'm consuming has extremely complex types. And `libraryFunctionThatWeCantChange` is just an example. The type `SecondParam` that you declare is what i want to declare from the typescript infer. The problem is that the library exports the function but dont exports the typings. I want to declare a type from the function parameters. But as the second parameter type is "calculated", I cant find the way (if it exists). I've added images with the "real problem" in the question. In this real problem, the second arg type is calculated from the Object type and first parameter type